# Can we have links of related lists in a VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a VF page in which i have related lists displayed using

```
  <apex:relatedList list="NOTESANDATTACHMENTS"/>
```

Is there a way i can have the link of the related list on the top of the page like the ones in standard page? The reason for this is that my VF page is pretty long and the user needs to scroll to get the view the notes and attachment list.

is there any way we can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, but you can always use anchor links.

```
<a href="#mylist">Go to related list</a>
...

<a id="mylist" />
<apex:relatedList list="NOTESANDATTACHMENTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The relationship name for the Notes and Attachments related list has been changed in winter 14 release.
you can show the attachement in the relatedlist tag.

`apex:relatedList list="CombinedAttachments" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"`
in the VF page if you are using Standard controller then there is no need to add subject attribute.